# How to show a textbox, button, etc in a Java Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

How can I show common GUI elements such as :

- Textbox
- Button
- Radios/Dropdowns
- Labels

etc in a java applet which would be run from a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [applet tutorial](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/) starts from the beginning, and covers [GUI components](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/GuiExample.html).

There are plenty of other [applet tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=applet+tutorial) around of course, almost all of which will cover GUI work.

Answer (score 1):

[`JApplet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) and [`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) both extend [`Container`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), so you just [set the layout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager)) and [add](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) the components like you would in any other Swing GUI.